# How do I error handle when a cell is blank and there are many routines

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have a sheet with a lot of code that I have worked on throughout the last couple of years but I am new to VBA and did not incorporate any error handling. I tried a few things but I could never make it work. It did not really affect me until recently. Most of my routines are driven by a cell that contains a sales price (cell D5). I am using Worksheet_Change ByVal target as range to change things when different cells are changed so when the sales price is changed it starts running routines. 
What I have noticed is that this particular routine is the first one that gives me a VBA error if I delete the sales price in cell D5. So I thought I can ask someone to give me a simple code to catch the empty cell before the routine fires and maybe a popup saying "Sales Price cannot be blank" and perhaps revert to the previous value of that cell. The debug error takes me to the line of code that starts with "If Sheets("Main").Range("D6").Value < 0.8001"

```
Sub Calc_MI()
If Sheets("Main").Range("D12").Value = "FHA" Then
Sheets("Main").Range("D16").Value = 0.85
Else
If Sheets("Main").Range("D6").Value < 0.8001 Or 
   Sheets("Main").Range("D12").Value = "VA" Then
   Sheets("Main").Range("D16").Value = ""
Else
If Sheets("Main").Range("G14").Value > 0.45 Then
   Sheets("Main").Range("D16").Value = (Sheets("Closing 
   Costs").Range("BP100").Value + Sheets("Closing 
   Costs").Range("BP101").Value + Sheets("Closing 
   Costs").Range("BP102").Value)
 Else
 Sheets("Main").Range("D16").Value = (Sheets("Closing 
 Costs").Range("BP100").Value + Sheets("Closing 
 Costs").Range("BP102").Value)
 End If
 End If
 End If
 End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: And what’s the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could place this in "Main" sheet code pane

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then
            MsgBox "Sales Price cannot be blank"
            Application.EnableEvents = False ' disable events to prevent change event fire in an infinite loop
            Target.Value = oldVal ' restore old backup value
            Application.EnableEvents = True ' enable events back
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then oldVal = Target.Value ' if D5 selected then backup its value
End Sub
```